# Difference of couchapp between Cloudant & CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, underscore.js, couchapp, cloudant

I built a simple testing couchapp using the python tool "couchapp".

The app works well on my local native CouchDB and also replicate fine to Cloudant. However the map function won't work on Cloudant. I nailed down the problem to the use of underscore.js. Without using it, map works on Cloudant.

So the question is: what's the couchapp difference between Cloudant and CouchDB? Versions?

And, if I really want to use underscore.js on Cloudant, any special rule to follow?

Here's my simple map.js for your reference:

```
function(doc) {
    var u = require("views/lib/underscore-min");
    if (doc.series) {
        emit(doc._id, u.omit(doc,'_id','_rev'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that Cloudant doesn't support  server side commonjs: https://cloudant.com/blog/app-management/#.VM7rwnb6KSg

The hint was 2 years ago. Is it still the same now? ...

Comment: Well.. it's officially supported: https://cloudant.com/blog/cloudant-supports-commonjs-and-new-db-core-releases/#.VM72_Hb6KSg

But how come my case won't work?